# "Wear" vs "wore" vs "put on"

Tags: word-meaning

I know the difference between the verbs "wear" and "put on", but due to my first language, things become a little tricky when I use the verb "wore". Please cosider the following example:

1. He was wearing glasses = He had glasses on. (It's not an action)
2. He put on his glasses. (It's an action)
3. He wore glasses.

I'm not sure how the third sentence is semantically different from number 1 and 2.  Does it have the same meaning as the first sentence or the second one? i.e. is it an action or not an action? Under what circumstances would we use number 3 instead of number 1?

All the sources I found discuss the difference between "wear" and "put on", which I already know, but none discuss the past tense of the verb "wear".

Comment: The normal past tense rules apply to 'wear' as apply to other verbs. https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-wear.html

Comment: Both parts of (3) mean the same as (1) - but _He wore glasses_ can also mean that he habitually wore spectacles because his sight was defective.

Answer (score 1):

*Wear* means *have on*, not *put on*.

*Wore* means *had on* not *put on*.

So 3 means 1, not 2.